# Unable to use << parameters.my_param >> in job run step

Tags: parameters, circleci

I'm attempting to pass a URL as a parameter to a CircleCi job (as part of a `Workflow`).

I know `parameters` can be used in a `When` step (as `conditions`), however I can't find any way of passing a parameter to a job, in order to use it in the Run steps.

Ultimately I would like to trigger this job via an API request from another project.

```
version: 2
jobs:
  smokes:
    parallelism: 4
    working_directory: ~/regression-repo/
    parameters:
        target_url:
           type: string
           default: <defaultURL>
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:latest-browsers

    steps:
     - checkout
     - run:
          name: Run smoke tests
          command: |
            TEST_FILES=$(circleci tests glob "./tests/**/*.js" | circleci tests split --split-by=filesize)
            TEST_NAME=$(basename -- ${TEST_FILES%.js})
            TARGET_URL= << parameters.target_url >>
            printf "\nTest files:\n$TEST_FILES\nURL:\n$TARGET_URL\n"
            TEST_PATH=$TEST_FILES RESULTS_NAME=$TEST_NAME URL=$TARGET_URL npm run smokes


workflows:
  version: 2

  build_on_changes:
    jobs:
      - smokes
```

I would expect this to pass the URL to the run step... however I get the error:

```
/bin/bash: line 4: warning: here-document at line 2 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `parameters.target_url')
/bin/bash: -c: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
Exited with code 2
```

I've tried adding quotes (single, double, backticks), as well as just echoing the param:

```
steps:
      - run:
          name: target_url
          command: |
            echo << parameters.target_url >>
```

However I keep hitting the same error message.

I've put it through a YAML parser and verified it's not a config issue... Any ideas how I can pass a parameter (URL) to my smoke job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was related to the CircleCi Config version (2, when it should be 2.1 in order to use parameters). Simple but I somehow missed it for a couple of days:

```
version: 2.1
jobs:
  smokes:
    parallelism: 4
    working_directory: ~/regression-repo/
    parameters:
        target_url:
           type: string
           default: <defaultURL>
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:latest-browsers

    steps:
    .........
```